# How to Update some records with still maintain other records in Codeignitter?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update, codeigniter-3

Table **Info** :

| id-data | id-note | note |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | I went home with John Harrison |
| 2 | 5 | I had dinner with John Harrison |
| 3 | 5 | I went shopping with John Harrison |
| 4 | 3 | I had dinner with John Harrison |

I want to **update** "*John Harrison*" in *note* **where** *id-note (5)*, with "*Sebastian*" but still **maintain** the other sentence, using codeigniter-3 model-controller

Table **Info** after update should be :

| id-data | id-note | note |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | I went home with Sebastian |
| 2 | 5 | I had dinner with Sebastian |
| 3 | 5 | I went shopping with Sebastian |
| 4 | 3 | I had dinner with John Harrison |

All suggestions will be very helpful.

Comment: Why don't you just select all records with note like `John Harrison` then replace them with `Sebastian` by PHP and finally, update those records with new values after replacements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  made an example for you that I think works for you.

you need to find and use `str_replace` for change your note. see example:

```
      $findText    = 'John Harrison';
      $replaceText = 'Sebastian';

      $this->db->select('*');
      $this->db->from('test');
      $this->db->where('id-note',5);
      $query = $this->db->get();
      $result = $query->result_array();

      foreach($result as $val) {
          $youText   = $val['note'];
          $replace_1 = ["$findText"];
          $replace_2 = ["$replaceText"];
          $result = str_replace($replace_1, $replace_2, $youText);

          $updateText = array(
              'note'=>$result
          );
          $this->db->where('id-data',$val['id']);
          $this->db->update('info',$updateText);
      }
```